# How to use sbt native packager with subprojects (sbt 0.13)

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

I have an sbt project with a multitude of subprojects and external library dependencies. `build.sbt` goes like this:

```
val extlib1 = "xy.xxx" % "lib1" % "1.0+"
val extlib2 = "xy.yyy" % "lib2" % "1.0+"
val extlib3 = "xy.zzz" % "lib3" % "1.0+"

lazy val core=project settings (
  name:="cor",
  libraryDependencies++=Seq(extlib1)
)

lazy val servercore=project settings (
  name:="srvcore",
  libraryDependencies++=Seq(extlib1,extlib2)
) dependsOn(core)

lazy val masterserver=project settings (
  name:="mastersrv",
  mainClass:=Some("masterserver")
) dependsOn(servercore)

lazy val otherserver=project settings (
  name:="othersrv",
  libraryDependencies++=Seq(extlib3),
  mainClass:=Some("otherserver")
) dependsOn(servercore)

// Only for aggregating the builds of the subprojects
lazy val root=project in file(".") settings(name:="proj") aggregate(
  core,servercore,masterserver,otherserver
)
```

So actually the project creates several programs ("masterserver", "otherserver") which depend on external libraries and a subset of the subprojects of this project itself.

What I want to have is a complete set of JARs needed to start the master server or the other server, *seperated for each*. So, I'd like to have e.g. `masterserver/target/<whatever>` containing

```
mastersrv.jar
srvcore.jar   (needed by mastersrv.jar)
cor.jar       (needed by srvcore.jar)
lib1.jar      (needed by mastersrv and srvcore)
lib2.jar      (needed by srvcore)
<whatever>.jar  (further libs needed by lib1 or lib2)
```

and a `otherserver/target/<whatever>` with similar content (it would have to add `lib3.jar` also, as that is needed by `othersrv.jar`.

How to do that? Can I perform this with the native packager? Issuing `stage` in the root project does nothing (because there is no `mailClass`?). Issuing `masterserver/state` gives an error message

```
> masterserver/stage
[error] No such setting/task
[error] masterserver/stage
[error]                   ^
```

I must admit that I do not get a real clue out of the native packager plugin documentation. How can I archive what I want to have?

Edit: Of course, I am not bound to the directory stuff. If I get multiple ZIP files in the main `target` directory, it's o.k., too. I only want to have all dependencies of a subproject at one location.

Edit 2: Ok, I learned that the Play! framework does exactly what I want. And it uses the sbt native packager for it. How can I archieve a recursive universal packaging of subprojects in non-Play sbt-handled projects which use Java as programming language?

Answer (score 7):

Well, the answer was quite straight-forward once I tested a bit around. First, put the native packager in the project-global `project/plugins.sbt`

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "0.6.4")
```

Then, put the configuration for the native packager in the `build.sbt` in the **subproject**. In the example above, put the following into `masterserver/build.sbt`:

```
// Setup the packager
packageArchetype.java_application

// Enable JAR export for staging
exportJars := true
```

The set of needed JAR files will be put into the subproject's `target` directory, in this example into `masterserver/target/universal/stage/lib`

The rest of the subproject's configuration can stay in the global `build.sbt`, but I found no way of configuring the native packager that way.

Comment: Thanks for self-answering. I found it quite helpful :)

Comment: This answer should probably be updated to reflect use of sbt `AutoPlugin` facility as used in the 1.x line of `sbt-native-packager`.

Comment: Well, indeed, the answer is now more than two years old. Unfortunately, we have not changed or updated our toolchains since then, so I must admit that I have no experience with AutoPlugin. :-(